# Finding the generated magnetic field of a Hall generator

Tags: unit-conversion, quantum-hall-effect

I've been using a Hall generator to generate a particular magnetic field by applying a current. I need to work out what field this corresponds to in Tesla. All I have to go on is what's in the photo included. This says it's open circuit which I don't understand in terms of how there can be a non-zero current with no resistance. How do I translate this?[image]

Comment: 1 tesla = 10,000 gauss and possibly the voltage was measured without drawing current from the device. Could be a potentiometer type circuit?

Comment: Well we applied a current of 20A to the system and I'm not sure how this converts to a magnetic field.

Comment: I thought that it might be referring to the voltage measurement?

Comment: Well if there is no resistance in the system because it's an open I'm not sure how I can convert amps to volts.

Comment: I assumed that it was of this type?

Comment: Yes this exact one.

Comment: The link (https://www.lakeshore.com/Documents/Magnetic%20Field%20Sensors_L.pdf) seemed to have disappeared from my previous comment.  The data is for the load resistor, as they call it, not being present.

Comment: Yes this seems to be the same. I'm still unsure how it would work though.